# Macbook Pro 15-inch replacement battery

Tags: macbook, battery, charging

So I've finally got to the 300+ cycles with my MBP 2008's original battery. Apple is pretty much "on the money" too! I am at 79% Health and getting the **Condition: Replace Soon** warning.

So I went out to the closest Apple Store and bought a replacement. I would like to get the same lifespan out of my replacement if possible. My question is:

The battery comes with a 2 dot (green) charge on the indicator, should I put the battery in and let it run down and do a full recharge **OR** begin charging it immediately and then let it run all the way to empty and recharge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple pretty much has that one covered [Battery Calibration](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1490)

Comment: Thanks Mark, I understand how calibration works, my question was more so from when the battery is new out of the box and which path to take.

Comment: After researching this further ... calibration is the way to go even with a new battery.

Answer (score 3):

Drain it and then charge it.